AWS secretsmanager - mysql jdbc connector throwing "No Driver has been registered with name, com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
I'm trying to setup AWS secretsmanager and jdbc connectivity for mysql in a spring boot project. Followed the official documentation and also this article but getting the error below:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Driver has been registered with name, com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. 
Please check your system properties or secretsmanager.properties for typos. Also ensure that the Driver registers itself.
        at com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerDriver.getWrappedDriver(AWSSecretsManagerDriver.java:266)
        at com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerDriver.acceptsURL(AWSSecretsManagerDriver.java:279)
        at com.

I have the following in my pom.xml
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.secretsmanager</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-secretsmanager-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>

and the following in my application.properties:
spring.datasource.username=<SECRET_KEY_NAME>
spring.datasource.url=jdbc-secretsmanager:mysql://localhost:3306
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerMySQLDriver

Has anyone encountered and been able to resolve this?
